# How to use CompositeForeignKey in a model

Tags: python, django, foreign-keys

I have installed django-composite-foreignkey using pip in an Anaconda cmd interface while having the virtual environment active.

When I use CompositeForeignKey like this:

```
PersOrg = CompositeForeignKey(Organisation, on_delete=CASCADE, to_fields={'ClientId', 'OrgCode'})
```

I get the error: NameError: name 'CompositeForeignKey' is not defined

I have tried:

```
import django-composite-foreignkey
```

but get the error: import django-composite-foreignkey ^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax.

How do I make the model aware of the existence of CompositeForeignKey? or is there a better way to refer to a multiple field foreign key.

I have a database where multiple clients will register and e.g. define their own staff working in their organisation.

Typically, a model will have this definition:

```
class Person(models.Model):
ClientId = models.ForeignKey('clients.Client', on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                             to_field='id')
PersNumber = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=False)
PersSurName = models.CharField(max_length=40, null=False)
PersNames = models.CharField(max_length=40, null=False)
PersIsStaff = models.BooleanField(null=False)
PersMobile = models.CharField(max_length=13)
PersWork = models.CharField(max_length=13, blank=True)
PersEmail = models.EmailField(max_length= 80, blank=True)
PersWorkTitle = models.CharField(max_length=40)
PersOrg = CompositeForeignKey(Organisation, on_delete=CASCADE,
                                to_fields={'ClientId', 'OrgCode'})

class Meta:
    unique_together = (('ClientId', 'PersNumber'),)

def __str__(self):
    """Return a string representation of the model"""
    return str(self.PersNumber) + ' - ' + self.PersSurName + ' - ' + self.PersNames
```

In each model there will be a client id and one (or more) other fields that are unique together.

As in the example above, the field PersOrg is a foreign key to the table 'Organisation' where the fields 'ClientId', 'OrgCode' define the foreign key.

The question has been asked and answered in this forum but I cannot get CompositeForeignKey to work.

Help will be appreciated

Regards,

Phlip

Comment: Believe me this is not worth the trouble. Nowadays the pattern is to have an auto incrementing primary key in every table and use that pk as the foreign key and that pattern works wonderfully well with django.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`django-composite-foreignkey` is the name of the project, but the Python package name is `compositefk`, as can be seen in the [test app](https://github.com/onysos/django-composite-foreignkey/blob/master/testapp/models.py). So your import should be:

```
from compositefk.fields import CompositeForeignKey
```

I thought this was a strange mistake to make, but looking at [the documentation](https://github.com/onysos/django-composite-foreignkey/blob/307c2a077ef273ba899cfa1d32dce7ea3f83e1db/docs/quickstart.rst) they never actually show the import, so I think it's fair to say that the documentation let you down here.

Note that Python identifiers can't contain `-`, which is why you got a syntax error.

Comment: That helped me very much and I resolved the issue. Thank you.